# how to assert Yii log messages in a phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii, phpunit

Yii has logging system built. In certain case I want to make sure that logging is done properly, i.e. correct message is getting logged as "error" or "warning".
How can I read these messages from phpunit test case?

Example Code:

```
public function actionDownload($id)
{
    $order = self::$dic->get('StoreOrder')->findByPk($id);
    $logged = Yii::app()->user->getState('usermodel');
    if(!isset($order->id_user))
    {
        Yii::log("could not get user id from order $id","error");
        return false;
    }
    if(!isset($logged->id_user))
    {
        Yii::log("could not get user id from from session","error");
        return false;
    }
    # other code...
}
```

I need to check that correct `Yii::log` was fired in particular test condition.

Comment: An example of your test code would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably need to create a new custom `CLogRoute` (let's call it `CTestLogRoute`), which does something like push log messages to an internal array. Then add some methods to retrieve the last log message pushed to the internal array (let's call it `getLastLogEntry()`), which you can use in your `assert()` statement.

You can add the special log route to your unit test `config` file like so:

```
'components'=>array(
  'log'=>array(
    'class'=>'CLogRouter', 
    'routes'=>array(
       array(
         'class'=>'CTestLogRoute', // custom log router which will save the messages
         'levels'=>'info, error, warning', // select the level you want piped in here
       ),
    ),
 ),
```

Then in your unit test you can do something like this:

```
foreach (Yii::app()->log->routes as $route)
  if ($route instanceof CTestLogRoute) // find our log route
    $lastLogValue = $route->getLastLogEntry(); // get the last entry
$this->assertEquals('Expected last log value',$lastLogValue);
```

I haven't tried it, but it should work just fine. I like the ambition of even testing the error log entries!

Answer (score 0):

There's a wiki article which describes exactly what you have to do here:

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/340/access-log-output-from-unit-tests